# $\log((n^2!))>n^2$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I need to prove that $\log\bigl((n^2)!\bigr)$ is bigger than $c\mkern1mu n^2$ for some $c$ and starting from a specific location.

How can I do that?

I know the following:

[image]

**Note: My logarithm is to the base of 2.**

Comment: Any idea please?

Comment: you maybe want to use the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\log(k) > (n^2-n)\log(n)$

Comment: This follows directly from $\mathrm{log}\ n! = \Theta(n\mathrm{log}\ n)$ of which there many proofs online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are almost done. Look at each term of
\begin{align*}
\log (n^2) + \log (n^2 - 1) + \dotsm + \log (2) + \log (1) \\
= 2 \log (n) + \underbrace{\log (n^2 - 1) + \dotsm + \log (2)}_{n^2 - 2 \text{ terms}} + \log (1)
\end{align*}
Of course, we can assume that $n > 2$, so that $2 \log (n) > 2$. Now, the first term is $2 \log (n) > 2$. The last term is $\log(1) = 0$. The remaining terms $(n^2-2)$ terms are all at least $1$.
Thus, this whole thing is greater than
$$ 2 + \underbrace{1 + \dotsm + 1}_{n^2 - 2 \text{ terms}} + 0 = n^2$$
Can you do the rest?